# Shorthand for creating an array of string values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a quick way to create a literal array filled with strings in javascript?

I am coming from Ruby, where using %w{} allows for you to omit quotation marks and commas around the values of the array. For example:

```
array = %w{a b c}
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

is equivalent to the standard syntax for literal assignment:

```
array = ["a", "b", "c"]
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Is there anything similar to this in javascript?

Comment: nope sorry that does not exist at this time. you could do `"a b c".split(" ")`, but that's extra overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better way, but this would work:

```
var array = 'abc'.split('');  // ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

And for words:

```
var array = 'domo arigato mr. roboto'.split(' ');
 // ['domo', 'arigato', 'mr.', 'roboto']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it's a proper way or not but I go with

```
'abc'.split(''); //returns array
```